# How access session username after session is authenticated in other controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using `Ember-simple-auth` to authenticate my routes, and is working fine. I have:

```
login - login route
index - after login in ok
```

And i'm using the ember-cli-notification to pop up this message:

```
"Welcome USER NAME"
```

Like this, in IndexController:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  init () {
    this.notifications.addNotification({
      message: 'Welcome USER NAME',
      type: 'success',
      autoClear: true,
      clearDuration: 5000
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to ask... how can i access the properties of the current logged user? I'm in a complete different controller, so i don't have any idea in how can i do that...

And.. i would like to ask if possible.. i am using the init function for this.. am i doing it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `session` service. If you return the current user's details in the response, they are persisted in `session.data.authenticated`.

```
// app/controllers/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 session: Ember.inject.service(),
 init () {
   this.notifications.addNotification({
     message: `Welcome ${this.get('session.data.authenticated.name')}`,
     type: 'success',
     autoClear: true,
     clearDuration: 5000
   });
 }
});
```

Refer [Docs](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#basic-usage) &
[Dummy app](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/897779e18be7fbdb3bcf612ae7be188866e6c927/tests/dummy/app/services/session-account.js#L10-L16)

Hope it helps...

Comment: about use init to do what... is that the correct way?

Comment: to do this** @selvagsz

Comment: I'd prefer to have this top level route's `activate` hook. Probably, in `application` route

Nevertheless, if you override `init` anywhere, make sure to call `this._super()`
https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/19/2015-dont-dont-override-init

Comment: More apt hook would be `sessionAuthenticated` of the application route mixin that ember-simple-auth provides

http://pastie.org/10573311

http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/ApplicationRouteMixin.html#method_sessionAuthenticated